# Update a recordset in Access 2010

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access-2010

I need a simple update query in VB where I can update some fields in the last record in my table.

[image]

I have this form with a set of comboboxes and when I press the `Edit` button, I should be able to select different values from the comboboxes and when I press `Save`, it should update the last record in my table with the latest selections in my comboboxes. Please advise.

I have the following code but it's just rubbish and it does not edit anything in my table.

```
Private Sub Command51_Click()
Dim RS As DAO.Recordset
Dim RecID As Integer
Set RS = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Data", dbOpenDynaset)
RecID = DLast("[ID]")
RS.MoveFirst
Do Until RS.EOF
If RS("ID") = RecID Then
    RS.Edit
    RS("WLAN") = Me.Text34
    RS("Controller Version") = Me.Text38
    RS("AP Model") = Me.Text36
    RS("Security") = Me.Text39
    RS("Wired Network") = Me.Text37
    RS("Installation Type") = Me.Text40
    RS("Quoted Device") = Me.Text41
    RS.Update
    RS.Close

     End With

     MsgBox "Device info were edited and stored.", vbExclamation
```

End Sub

And here's the table structure [Edited]

[image]

Comment: `I have this form` <---- Which form? Please include a screenshot? StackOverflow allows copy/paste from clipboard.

Comment: I'm sorry. Please check out the below image http://imageshack.com/a/img33/192/qjk6.jpg

Comment: Good. Please also include your code and table structure.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you're telling us, I would change the default values to the current values of each control on the form on the Form_Current event.  Also, in Form Design mode, set all of the controls to be Locked.  When the user clicks on the Edit button, I would simply move to a new record.  Of course, the user would be able to edit the current record unless you locked all the controls.  Please be warned that I haven't tested this code.

```
Private Sub Form_Current()
   On Error Resume Next   'not all controls have the "DefaultValue" property, such as labels'
   Dim ctl as Control
   For Each ctl in Me.Controls
       ctl.Locked = Not Me.NewRecord
       ctl.DefaultValue = ctl.Value
   Next ctl
End Sub

Private Sub cmdEdit_Click()
   Access.Application.DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdRecordsGoToNew
End Sub

Private Sub cmdSave_Click()
   Me.Dirty = False
End Sub
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it did not work. Can you please give me the correct syntax of Update query because I've tried so many and each returned an error. Just a simple update that edits the last recordset. Thanks.

Comment: It worked. I used the following code:                             Dim RS As DAO.Recordset
Set RS = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Data", dbOpenDynaset)
RS.MoveLast
RS.Edit
RS("WLAN") = Me.Text34
RS("Controller Version") = Me.Text38
RS("AP Model") = Me.Text36
RS("Security") = Me.Text39
RS("Wired Network") = Me.Text37
RS("Installation Type") = Me.Text40
RS("Quoted Device") = Me.Text41

RS.Update
Set RS = Nothing
                                                                                  Thank you Bobort for taking the time to help. I appreciate it.